# AWS: How to Programmatically get AWS daily usage report/data for linked account

Tags: amazon-web-services

For non linked account, I know there is Detailed Billing Report can be saved to S3, however for linked account this feature is disabled.

I did some research, current have 2 options:

1. use usage report in https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html, however I am not sure if it can be programmatically downloaded. Is there way to access such service using API key? Is it a open API of AWS ?
2. use data in cloudwatch. But not sure if detailed usage data can be retrieved from cloudwatch. And is there API to retrieve it.

It's emergency, could somebody give me some suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? Billing data like expenses per service?

Comment: I want to know the usage per service, for example how many S3 storage used, how many network brandwidth used